# Select2 change event is triggered when knockout's valueHasMutated method is called

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I have a view model that is observed by knockout like I defined below

```
var viewModel = function() {
     var self = this;
     self.selected = ko.observable({
         people : ko.observableArray(),
         message : ko.observable()
     });
     self.notify = function() {
         self.selected.valueHasMuateted();
     }
}
var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And I am using this viewModel in a page with ajax request like below. **PS: project.Get** method is a simple Ajax helper and there is not problem with that method.

```
//other codes

project.Get("/Data/People", function(data) {
    if(data){
        for(var i in data) {
            var row = data[i];
            vm.selected().people.push(row);
        }
        vm.notify();
    }
})
```

After ajax request there is a table that is listening people array on html. Data is pushed to to array but table cannot understand the change. In order to notify view i am calling **vm.notify** method to force update UI.

First : Do I have to call **valueHasMutated** method to update UI?

Second : I have some other elements which are connected to viewModel like select2, dataTables etc. After calling **valueHasMutated** method, select2 component' change event is triggered automatically.

What are the reasons?

Comment: should work without valueHasMutated .. the reason it can not that on some stage you re-assign observable array value. Check out fiddle with your js code:http://jsfiddle.net/oshumelyuk/k9n2rLax/1/ Everything works as expected without notification

Comment: Yes it is working by default but as I said when i use select2 on page it is triggering change event. Спасибо!!!

Comment: probably you need to create custom binding for select2. See my answer for related question. There's an example with chosen plungin (should be similar to select2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788706/in-a-knockout-custom-binding-how-do-you-know-which-value-is-triggering-the-upda/50791193#50791193